# How to debug react-native-reanimated 2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

Is there a way to debug the current .value of a sharedValue, something like this?

```
const progress = useSharedValue(0);

<Animated.Code>
    {() => debug('progress: ', progress.value)}
</Animated.Code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use useDerivedValue for logging

```html
import { useDerivedValue } from 'react-native-reanimated';

useDerivedValue(() => {
  console.log(progress.value);
});
```